# Reactive Cocoa - View visibility based on scrollview content offset

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to change the visibility of a view based on the current content offset y value of a scrollview using Reactive Cocoa. My thought was to create an observer on an NSNumber property that would get changed in the scrollview delegate's scrollViewDidScroll. Here's the code that I've added to viewDidLoad:

```
RAC(self.headerView, hidden) = [RACObserve(self, offset) subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *value) {
    return @([value integerValue] > 0);
}];
```

Setting a breakpoint on the return statement, I see that this is called once, but never again. What am I missing?

Comment: So, I got the behavior I was looking for, but please correct me if I'm doing something wrong. I created a RACSubject property called contentOffset, and in scrollViewDidScroll, I call sendNext on that property. I'm then using combineLatest:reduce: to set whether or not the view is hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you describe, implementing a method that calls `-sendNext:` on a subject, is so common that there's a method that does that all for you: `-rac_signalForSelector:`. In the case of delegates, you can call `-rac_signalForSelector:` on the delegate, like so:

```
RAC(self.headerView, hidden) = [[(id)scrollView.delegate
    rac_signalForSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)]
    reduceEach:^(UIScrollView *scrollView) {
        return @(scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0);
    }];
```

One gotcha that comes up with delegates is that you must make sure you invoke any `-rac_signalForSelector:` calls *before* assigning the delegate.

Comment: There's also `-rac_signalForSelector:fromProtocol:` for methods that don't accept or return all object arguments. Not an issue here, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @DaveLee could you explain how `map:` allows `UIScrollView` to be accessed directly in the block? My attempts to do this don't work. I always get `RACTuple`.

Comment: I'm assuming it only works if the method only accepts a single argument.

Comment: @PaulYoung My mistake, this should be `-reduceEach:` not `-map:`, I'll fix the answer. This is a mistake I always seem to do :/, thanks for catching it.

Comment: Great example. By the way if you need to get the signal only when a change occur you can use "distinctUntilChanged". This will avoid calling set hidden multiple times.